# Formatted iMac in case sensitive instead of journaled

Tags: macos, disk-utility, hdd

Recently I tried restoring my iMac. 
To restore it they said to go to Disk Utility, Macintosh HD, and to erase it in the journaled format. 
I forgot to re-format it and I'm pretty sure I erased it in the format of case sensitive.

I then tried to reinstall Mac Os anyways but at the end of every Install, They said that there was a problem and suggested I do it again. I did it multiple times and kept getting the same result.

I don't know what came to me but I decided to delete everything except for the Apple HDD thing in the internal thin of the iMac. I don't know what to do, I'm completely lost and in desperate need of help

Comment: Can you still boot into Recovery (with Cmd-R) or Internet Recovey (Cmd-Opt-R, if your Mac supports this already and is online)?

Comment: Yes I can. I still have access to MacOs utilities. I tried reinstalling MacOs but it lead me back to the flashing folder with a question mark. I dont know if this adds anything but Macintosh HD is now named Untitled.

Comment: While in Recovery, can't you reformat the main drive into HFS+ Journaled/non-case sensitive?